# How can we maintain Immutability of a class with a mutable reference

Tags: java, collections, immutability

I know all the basic rules to make our class immutable but I am a little confused when there is another class reference. I know if there is collection instead of `Address` then we can make use of `Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(modifiable));` and then we can make our class immutable. But in below case I am still unable to get the concept.

```
public final class Employee{
    private final int id;
    private Address address;
    public Employee(int id, Address address)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.address=address;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public Address getAddress(){
        return address;
    }
}

public class Address{
    private String street;
    public String getStreet(){
        return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street){
        this.street = street;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Employee` isn't immutable, and there's not much you can do to change that if you can't change the `Address` class to support at a minimum copying, but preferably making `Address` immutable in the first place.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, the concept is reading the JLS and understanding it.  Chapter 17 of the JLS "Threads and Locks" describes memory visibility and synchronization.  [Section 17.5 "Final Field Semantics"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) describes the memory visibility semantics for final fields. That section says in part:

> final fields also allow programmers to implement thread-safe immutable objects without synchronization. A thread-safe immutable object is seen as immutable by all threads, even if a data race is used to pass references to the immutable object between threads. This can provide safety guarantees against misuse of an immutable class by incorrect or malicious code. final fields must be used correctly to provide a guarantee of immutability.
>
> The usage model for final fields is a simple one: Set the final fields for an object in that object's constructor; and do not write a reference to the object being constructed in a place where another thread can see it before the object's constructor is finished. If this is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's final fields. It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are.

So you need to:

1. Make `address` both final and private.
2. For any mutable object, you must prevent the reference to that object from being seen externally.

In this case, #2 probably means you can't return a reference to Address like you have with `getAddress()`.  **And** you have to make a defensive copy in the constructor.  I.e., make a copy of any mutable parameter, and store the copy in Employee.  If you can't make a defensive copy, there's really no way to make Employee immutable.

```
public final class Employee{
    private final int id;
    private final Address address;
    public Employee(int id, Address address)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.address=new Address();  // defensive copy
        this.address.setStreet( address.getStreet() );
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public Address getAddress() {
        Address nuAdd = new Address(); // must copy here too
        nuAdd.setStreet( address.getStreet() );
        return nuAdd;
}
```

Implementing `clone()` or something similar (a copy ctor) would make creating defensive objects easier for complicated classes.  However, the best recommendation I think would be to make `Address` immutable.  Once you do that you can freely pass around its reference without any thread-safety issues.

In this example, notice I do *NOT* have to copy the value of `street`.  `Street` is a String, and strings are immutable.  If `street` consisted of mutable fields (integer street number for example) then I *would* have to make a copy of `street` also, and so on ad infinitum.  This is why immutable objects are so valuable, they break the "infinite copy" chain.

Since this question is getting popular, I should also add a mention of [Brian Goetz's book,](https://jcip.net/) *Java Concurrency in Practice,* which is how I learned about these techniques, and I'm basically paraphrasing that book above.

Comment: mark, can you please tell me how to make a defensive copy of address. an example would be very helpful

Comment: great mark , i somehow getting the concept but as we already created Address object in Employee ()  constructor then why we are creating it again in getAdress() method

Comment: I said why, at least twice.  The JLS says the Employee object isn't immutable unless we prevent internal references from being seen.  If we use the value that was passed into the ctor, then anyone could be holding that reference.  Hence we can't use it, we have to make our own object that no one else can see.

Comment: In getAddress() method there is a mistake: it should be this.address.getStreet()

Answer (score 12):

Well there is steps provided by [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html)

> **A Strategy for Defining Immutable Objects**
>
> The following rules define a simple strategy for creating immutable
>   objects. Not all classes documented as "immutable" follow these rules.
>   This does not necessarily mean the creators of these classes were
>   sloppy — they may have good reason for believing that instances of
>   their classes never change after construction. However, such
>   strategies require sophisticated analysis and are not for beginners.
>
> - Don't provide "setter" methods — methods that modify fields or objects
>     referred to by fields.
> - Make all fields final and private.
> - Don't allow
>     subclasses to override methods. The simplest way to do this is to
>     declare the class as final. A more sophisticated approach is to make
>     the constructor private and construct instances in factory methods.
> - If
>     the instance fields include references to mutable objects, don't allow
>     those objects to be changed:
>
>   - Don't provide methods that modify the
>       mutable objects.
>   - Don't share references to the mutable objects. Never
>       store references to external, mutable objects passed to the
>       constructor; if necessary, create copies, and store references to the
>       copies. Similarly, create copies of your internal mutable objects when
>       necessary to avoid returning the originals in your methods.

Address class is mutable because you can modify it with the setStreet method.
So other class can modify this class.

We can defend against this by taking a copy of the of the Address instance when it is passed in rather than trusting the reference to the instance we are given.

Making Address object final

```
private final Address address;
```

Secondly,

```
this.address = new Address(address.getStreet());
```

Create constructor in Address class that sets Street.Remove setter method for street.

And finally instead of

```
public Address getAddress(){
    return address;
}
```

Use

```
public Address getAddress(){
    return new Address(address.getStreet());
}
```

Comment: Yes, i know but how can we implement last 2 points in  my case. can you tell me that

Comment: @user1111880 I have updated the answer... Refer http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2003/04/immutable.htm also

Comment: @user1111880 Please mark the solution as ACCEPTED if your problem is solved.In this way it will help others looking for similar problem

Answer (score 2):

If you want to encapsulate a **mutable object into an immutable one**, then you need to:

1. Create a **copy of the mutable object** (i.e. via copy constructor, cloning, serialization/deserialization, etc.);
   never store the reference to the original mutable object.
2. Never return the mutable object. If you must to, then **return a copy** of the object.
3. Avoid methods which can change the mutable object.

   ```
    public Employee(int id, Address address){
            this.id = id;
            this.address=new Address();  
            this.address.setStreet( address.getStreet() );
        }


    public Address getAddress() {
            Address nuAdd = new Address(); // must copy here too
            nuAdd.setStreet( address.getStreet() );
            return nuAdd;
       }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

In Employee class, return the deep clone copy of the address instance in the getAddress() method instead of returning original instance. So that if anybody changed the address instance, it can not reflect the original instance. But one condition, Address class must implements Cloneable interface.

```
public final class Employee{
     private final int id;
     private Address address;
     public Employee(int id, Address address) {
          this.id = id;
          this.address=address;
     }
     public int getId(){
          return id;
     }
     public Address getAddress() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
          return (Address) address.clone();
     }

}
```

Reference :-[Immutable Class in java](http://adnjavainterview.blogspot.com/2019/06/how-to-create-custom-immutable-class-with-mutable-object-reference-injava.html)

Answer (score 1):

So in your example `Employee` class is immutable, because once it is created, you can't change its state, because it has only getter methods.

`Address` class is `mutable` because you can modify it with the `setStreet` method.

So if you have other class which uses `Address` object, you are sure that that class can't modify the objects state.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use shallow copy using cloning

```
public final class Employee{
    private final int id;
    private Address address;
    public Employee(int id, Address address)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.address=address.clone();
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public Address getAddress(){
        return address.clone();
    }
}
```

Using this will create a separate object of Address in Employee class so in this case any changes made to the Address object passed as argument in Employee constructor will not change the member variable Address object of Employee class.

The getAddress() method is also returning a clone object so any changes made to the object fetched by this method do not effect the address object of Employee class.

**Note:**
To use this make Address class Cloneable.

Answer (score 1):

```
What is difference between the creating the object of employee calling the clonne method.
```

1) Creating employee object inside constructor and getter method and  setting the required Value by creating the object of employee inside constructor and setting the required field of employee into it as below.

```
Example : 

public final class Employee{
    private final int id;
    private final Address address;
    public Employee(int id, Address address)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.address=new Address();  // defensive copy
        this.address.setStreet( address.getStreet() );
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public Address getAddress() {
        Address nuAdd = new Address(); // must copy here too
        nuAdd.setStreet( address.getStreet() );
        return nuAdd;
}

2) cloning the employee object inside constructor and getter method as below.
Example : 

public final class Employee{
    private final int id;
    private Address address;
    public Employee(int id, Address address)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.address=address.clone();
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public Address getAddress(){
        return address.clone();
    }
}
```