# Why to make class final to create immutable object

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to follow code below. I am not exactly sure what happens at line #5 and why does statement at line #7 set the value of  tmp in immutable class to 10?

```
public class HelloWorld{ 
         public static void main(String []args){
            child c = new child(4);
            System.out.println(c.getTemp()); // line #4 prints 4
            immutable i = (immutable) c; //line #5
            System.out.println(i.getTemp()); // line #6 prints 4
            c.setTemp(10); //line #7
            System.out.println(i.getTemp()); // line 8 prints 10
         }
    }

    class immutable{
        private int tmp;       
        immutable(){              
        }
        immutable(int val){
            tmp = val;}
        public int getTemp(){
            return tmp; }        
     }

    class child extends immutable{
        private int tmp1;         
        child(){              
        }
        child(int y){
            super(y);
            tmp1= y;
        }
         public int getTemp(){
            return tmp1;}

         public void setTemp(int y){                 
            tmp1 = y;}
    }
```

Comment: Please follow the style guide for Java.

Comment: `child` is not immutable and line #5 is pointless.

Comment: I don't think this compiles.

Comment: `immutable` isn't immutable either.  The Java spec requires that all fields in an immutable object be `final`.  (This is totally different from making the class `final`.)  Since you don't do that, Java doesn't engage any of its special mechanism for to make the object immutable.  (Specifically there will be no *freeze-action* at the end of the ctor.)

Comment: @markspace Where does the spec define immutability?

Comment: @shmosel It's in [Chapter 17 Threads and Locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html) because the concept of immutability in Java is closely linked to memory visibility.  Specifically the [section 17.5 final Field Semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) *"final fields also allow programmers to implement thread-safe immutable objects without synchronization."* And all the other commentary in that section.

Comment: @shmosel I gave another answer where I talked about immutability and the Java spec in a bit more detail.  I'm sure Google will turn up lots of other examples as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109363/how-can-we-maintain-immutability-of-a-class-with-a-mutable-reference/34109446#34109446

Comment: @markspace They're linked, but not necessarily synonymous. Hence the careful wording "*thread-safe* immutable objects". And still there's no requirement that "all fields... be final". In fact, there are classes that are thread-safe and effectively immutable despite having non-final and mutable fields, such as `String`.

Comment: @shmosel String does use final fields though, and it is thread safe.  Its use of one single non-final field is the result of some rather tricky and careful analysis.  And if you make some other sort of "immutable" object in Java, besides a thread safe one as the spec describes, I think you would confuse a lot of programmers with your unique definition of "immutable," and be considered an outlier and not best practice.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the style and convention errors here and just focusing on your problem.

If your class is not final, there is a possibility of a subclass overriding the Immutability. Here is an example.

This is the Immutable class

```
public class Immutable {
 private final int value;

 public Immutable(int value) {
     this.value = value;
 }

 public int getValue() {
     return value;
 }
```

}

The class "Immutable" is not final, so I can extend it.

```
public class Mutable extends Immutable {
 private int newValue;

 public Mutable(int value) {
     super(value);

     newValue = value;
 }

 public int getValue() {
     return newValue;
 }
 public void setValue(int newValue) {
     this.newValue = newValue;
 }


}
```

Now to the main class,

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    Immutable immutable = createImmutableObject(10)
    System.out.println(immutable.getValue()); //This prints 10
    mutable.setValue(100);
    System.out.println(immObj.getValue()); //This prints 100
}

private Immutable createImmutableObject(int val){
    return new Mutable(val);
}
```

In the method createImmutableObject, I am returning a reference of type Immutable. Hence, developers using the API would assume that the returning object is Immutable. 
However, the object is of type Mutable (whose state can be changed) and just the reference is of the parent class. I can change the state of the returned object which would break the "immutability"

Comment: This is the correct answer, and also very complete.  Notice that in the class `Immutable` the field `value` is made `final`.  This is correct and the only way to make an immutable object in Java.  (There are actually ways to not use `final` fields, but they require careful and complex reasoning about the possible states of an object.  Not recommended for neophytes, and even experts can get it wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Class is made `final` for making it immutable so that it cannot be extended and its method overridden. Also, that is not the only thing that you do to make the class immutable.

Answer (score 0):

All Java functions are virtual - meaning, no matter what the declared type of a variable, you always get the underlying class's implementation of the method.

That means that any reference you have to `c`, no matter the declared type, will use `c`'s implementation of a method.

So, line 5 effectively does nothing (it would throw an exception if `c` didn't extend `immutable`).

When you call `getTemp` on `i`, you're invoking `c` class's (`child`'s) implementation of `getTemp`, even though the type of `i` is `immutable`.